# Latex->PDF errors in Miktex. Add several: par, enumerate,itemize

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex, sharelatex, texniccenter

After using more then 7 "\par" or 7 "\item" to appear errors. 
These errors are only if compile using Latex->PDF. 
If use Latex->DVI->PDF - not problems.
What's wrong? I'm notice.
 I work in TeXniCenter enviroment. 
When I try compile it in Sharelatex, compile was succesfull.  
[image]

Сode:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,final,14pt]{report}%{extreport}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{mathtext}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage {listing}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[space]{grffile}% дополнение, чтобы были пробелы в именах
\grffilesetup{% дополнение, чтобы имена файлов могли быть кириллицей (под Windows)
  encoding,
  filenameencoding=cp1251
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\huge}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage {ifpdf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage {rotating}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm} % математические дополнения от АМС
\usepackage{indentfirst} % отделять первую строку раздела абзацным отступом тоже
\usepackage{multirow} % улучшенное форматирование таблиц
\usepackage{ulem} % подчеркивания
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{utf8gost705u}%{abbrvnat}ugost2008s   utf8gost705u
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-15pt}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[space]{grffile} \grffilesetup{encoding,filenameencoding=cp1251}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setpapersize{A4} %210×297
\textheight=16cm % высота текста
\textwidth=5cm % ширина текста
\oddsidemargin=2.5cm % отступ от левого края
\topmargin=-1.5cm % отступ от верхнего края
\headheight= 1.5cm
\parindent=28pt % абзацный отступ
\parskip=03pt % интервал между абзацами
\tolerance=2000 % терпимость к "жидким" строкам
\footskip=1.5cm
\marginparsep =3.5cm
\marginparwidth=3cm
\sloppy
\makeatletter
\textwidth=175mm
\textheight=240mm
\headsep=5mm
\topmargin=5mm
\unitlength=1mm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\linespread{1.3} % полуторный интервал
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm} % Times New Roman
\frenchspacing
\finalhyphendemerits=5000
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\brokenpenalty=10000
\parfillskip=0pt plus .9\textwidth
\rhead{О ""}
\lhead{\includegraphics [width=0.02cm,height=0.5cm,scale=1.15\textwidth]{res/pic/logoon.eps}}
\rfoot{  \thepage}
\makeindex
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.61,0.73,0.35}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{
    \node[fill=mygreen,
        rounded corners,
        draw=white,
        line width=2pt,
        drop shadow,
        text width=4cm,
        inner sep=8pt,
        xshift=-2cm]
    at (frame.north){\bfseries\textcolor{white}{#1}};
}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    overlay={\mytitle{#2}},
    borderline={2pt}{0mm}{mygreen},
    borderline={.7pt}{1mm}{mygreen},
    frame hidden,
    arc=3mm,
    sidebyside,
    lefthand width=2.5cm,
    segmentation hidden,
    top=15pt,
    #1
}

\newcommand{\mysubsection}[1]{
\phantomsection
\subsection*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mysection}{ m O{#1}}{
\phantomsection
\section*{#2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{Li}{rgb}{0.88,0.5,1}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
\addto\captionsrussian{%
\def\contentsname{Содержание}%
\renewcommand\bibname{Список использованной литературы}
}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Приложения}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Приложения}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}
\newcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapters should use dots in ToC
\renewcommand{\@listi}{
\topsep=0pt 
\parsep=0pt 
\itemsep=0pt 

\itemindent=0pt 
\labelsep=1ex 
\leftmargin=\parindent 
\rightmargin=0pt} 

\def\redeflsection{\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{10em}}}
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\par%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Приложение}
  \def\sectionname{\appendixname}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\redeflsection}%
  \gdef\thesection{\appendixname\hspace{0.2cm}\@arabic{\c@section}}% 
}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}


\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrins}[1]{%
  \begingroup\fontfamily{erewhon-TLF}%
  \foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand\getcurrentref[1]{%
 \ifnumequal{\value{#1}}{0}
  {??}
  {\the\value{#1}}%
}  


\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\@arabic\c@table}
\@addtoreset{table}{section}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{res/pic/logoon.eps}
\end{minipage}
 & 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\large{ОО}\\ 
\footnotesize{А}\\
\footnotesize{И}\\
\small{\textbf{тел}}\\  
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
 \hfill \break
\begin{center}
\hfill \break
\hfill\break
\hfill \break
\newline
\newline
\normalsize \cyrins{\textbf{Отчёт}}
\break
\normalsize {по}\\
\large{Мног}\\
\hfill \break
\hfill \break
\hfill \break
\normalsize{р\hfill/ . /}\\
\normalsize{ \hspace{10cm} м.п.} \hfill \break
\hfill \break
\end{center}
\hfill \break
 «$\rule{0.75cm}{0.15mm}$» $\rule{2.5cm}{0.15mm}$ 2018 года \\
\hfill \break
\hfill \break
\begin{center} Ег 2018 \end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty} % 
\end {titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
%\addtotoc{Содержание}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\mychapter{0}{Введение}
\parРасти»\citep[][]{FZ123}(дан
\begin{centering}Необходимо.\end{centering}
\begin{enumerate}
\item   От 
\begin {item}   Несо:\end{item}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
    \item прению п;
    %\item превыш;%\end{item}
    %\item в;%\end{item}
        %\begin {item}    орош\end{item}
        %%\begin {item} за\end{item}
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\begin {item}   П\end{item}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I uploaded a part of code, which compiled succesfully. If uncomment items it may not work.

Comment: I never seen `\begin {item}   \end{item}`. Do you want `itemize`?

Comment: Initialy, it was: \begin{itemize}  \item qwerty \item fwqreqwe \end{itemize}

Comment: Cause of all problems where ".eps" in project, whitch i can try compile in Latex->pdf mode insteed Latex->dvi->pdf.